# open a dialog after select the dates using JQuery UI selectable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have designed a calendar.I have to open a dialog after selecting the dates.I used a filter option to select the dates. It is working fine. But the issue is dialog is opened for the inactive dates too. I want to open only for the available dates. Any suggestions?
the sample is in the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/8Sd53/3/)

```
jQuery("#calendar").selectable({
            filter: ".available",
            stop: function() {
            jQuery( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function() { 
            result.push( this.id); 
            });
            var width = 250;
            var height = 270;
            jQuery('#dialog').dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    height:height,
                    width:width,
                    resizable: false,
                    draggable: false,
                    dialogClass: "flora" 
                });
            jQuery('.flora.ui-dialog').css({ position:"absolute",top:"596px"});

            }
        });
```

[image]

Comment: Please re-frame the question. Where are you facing the problem? What is selectable? Your custom code? A publicly available jQuery plugin? Your code seems to be showing the modal when stop() is called. Who is calling it? If you are filtering to only show available dates, how is the user able to select non available dates? Could you provide a simplified example on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: The sample is http://jsfiddle.net/8Sd53/3/ It display the popup only by clicking the unavailable date.I want to show dialog after selecting the dates only. for example July 01 is unavailable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It works on my machine.

http://jsfiddle.net/8Sd53/3/

The change I have made is to use the `cancel` [option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/#option-cancel).

It will prevent the selection to start if you click on an element that matches the selector passed to the cancel option.

```
jQuery("#calendar").selectable({
    filter: ".available",
    cancel: ".disabled",  // this is the important piece        
    stop: function() {
    // remaining code
    }
```